Issue with RadioButtonFor in Index.cshtml - ASP.NET MVC 5
In my Index.cshtml in ASP.NET MVC 5, I have the following code and it works fine.
<div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsEnrolled) Enrolled </div> 

But, if I replace the same code with
<span style="margin-left:10px;">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsEnrolled, "Enrolled ") Enrolled 
</span>

then model. doesn't find IsEnrolled property.
What am I doing wrong?

Are you sure it works fine, without the >?

[model-view-controller] : For Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, please use [asp.net-mvc] or [asp.net-core-mvc] tag instead.

I missed it when I manually typed in the code here.  Yes, it works.
